# JSON Object/Array to Java object using GSON

Tags: java, json, gson

I have the following JSON structure received from a GET response:

```
[
   {
      "type":"unico",
      "line_items":{
         "meta_data":[
            {
               "id":"1",
               "key":"abc"
            },
            {
               "id":"2",
               "key":"cba"
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   {
      "type":"assinatura",
      "line_items":{
         "meta_data":{
            "4":{
               "id":"1",
               "key":"123"
            },
            "5":{
               "id":"2",
               "key":"321"
            }
         }
      }
   }
]
```

According to the structure the **meta_data** object can both be defined as a list of objects and an array of objects depending on the **type**.

I'm using the following definition to my LineItem.java class:

```
@SerializedName("meta_data")
@Expose
private MetaData metaData;
```

Which attends to the `"type":"assinatura"` type.

When parsing the JSON String to the Java object using GSON I get the error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was
>   BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 607 path $[0].line_items[0].meta_data

Is there a way I can have my Java class deal with both cases? From my position I can't alter the JSON structure.

Answer (score 0):

Use this [JsonToPojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) converter. It is very handy and It will create Pojo classes according to your Json response.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm using to create my classes however it only attends one of the definitions.

Comment: I didn't get you. What do you mean by **"only attends one of the definitions"?**

Comment: If I use the structure detailed in my question as the input on JsonToPojo it will return `private List<MetaData> metaData;` which doesn't work.
If I use the same structure removing the ("type":"assinatura") it will return `private MetaData metaData;` which doesn't work either.
It only changes the error from **Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY** to **Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT**

Comment: Let me check it. I will try to post solution for this. Can you alter the JSON response?

Comment: I can't alter the response. I receive it and pass it to a String object.

Comment: I managed to make it work changing `private MetaData metaData` to `private Object metaData`.